# Is it possible to have a dop down list in Adobe Livecycle with sub-sections?

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer

I want to make a drop down list with sub-sections in Livecycle. For example:

If my drop down gives some one the option of coffee or juice and they choose juice, then it asks what kind of juice.

-Coffee
   - black
   - sugar
   - cream
   - sugar & cream
-Juice
   - orange
   - apple
   - grape

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can make additional items like drop downs, text boxes, radio buttons etc. visible when a choice is made from a drop down. So if the user chooses coffee a radio button appears with decaf/regular and check boxes with cream, sugar etc.

The following script is from a form that had paper selection and based on on the paper selected a choice of paper weights available in a drop down became visible.

```
**This code in java script place in the mouse exit** 

if (Paperdropdownlist.rawValue == "Astrobrights") {
      Astrobrightweight.presence = "visible"; 
} else {
Astrobrightweight.presence = "invisible";           
}

**this script was in the form ready of the drop down that would become visible**

if (Paperdropdownlist.rawValue == "Astrobrights") {
      Astrobrightweight.presence = "visible"; 
} else {
Astrobrightweight.presence = "invisible";           
}
```